# How to clear file(s) selection from file input after the data has successfully be submitted?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I am using react.js, I have a form, that I am submitting to an API and the form works fine up to the point where I want to clear the fields. Well actually one field in particular, the file input. I can't get it to reset back to "No File Selected", I've tried creating a files= attribute and controlling it through the state, and everything. Nothing is working, what am I missing?

I only want to reset it when there has been a successful submission.

What is the right approach to this.

```
<input
    type="file"
    name="js-case-upload"
    className="form-control-static"
    filename={this.state.files}
    accept="image/*"
    onChange={ this._onChangeFileInput }
/>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considering the `input` have `id` `myFile`, then the file can be reset by vanilla javascript like the following:

`document.getElementById("myFile").value = "";`

Answer (score 2):

```
    const Upload = ({ onUpload }) => {
      const ref = useRef();

      const onChange = (e) => {
        onUpload(e.target.files, () => {
          ref.current.files = null;
        });
      };

      return <input ref={ref} onChange={onChange} type="file" />;
    };
```

I put a callback once I uploaded the file. On the callback I just set my files to null.

Comment: I'd rather use `ref.current.value = null`

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a `ref="file"` to you file input, and after submitting the data, use something like `this.refs.file.value = ''`.

**EDIT:**

Even a simpler solution: https://jsfiddle.net/n06qk9h4/

Comment: unless i'm missing something, that jsfiddle does not provide any useful info